# Correct placement of “s'il vous plait”

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, politesse

Whether speaking or writing, should I place “s'il vous plait” at the beginning or end of my sentence?

Answer (score 3):

À vrai dire il n'y a pas de place stricte et l'usage oral diffère souvent de l'écrit :

On peut le mettre au début, si dans une assemblée, au restaurant, ou dans un endroit où l'on a été présenté (il n'est pas nécessaire de le faire précédé par un *bonjour* de courtoisie) on s'adresse à quelqu'un pour un renseignement :

> *S'il vous plaît*, pourriez-vous ...

Les enfants l'emploient souvent pour tanner leurs parents avec plus ou moins d'insistance :

> Maman, maman, *s'il te plaît*, achète-moi ...

Sur un carton d'invitation qui demande une réponse (on doit par exemple informer l'expéditeur de sa venue ou non) on verra la mention :

> L'inauguration de .... [et en fin de texte les initiales] *R.S.V.P* (Répondez S'il Vous Plaît).

Placé au début, il peut interpeller une foule : donner un ordre une indication sans brutalité ni violence, uniquement pour informer d'un danger ou d'un risque :

> S'il vous plaît, s'il vous plaît, veuillez dégager le passage pour laisser passer ...

En fin de phrase, à la suite d'une demande amicale on peut le remplacer par :

> ..., comme il vous plaira !

La placement dans la phrase dépend du contexte, souvent cela n'a pas grande importance si la construction de la phrase est cohérente.

Pour s'amuser d'une fin :

> Cher lecteur, merci de corriger mes erreurs... s'il vous plaît !

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to say it is before, but commonly people will say it after. You can put it between a sentence too :

> Pouvez-vous, s'il vous plait, m'apporter le sel ?